# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at google.maps.Marker()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
    <script>
            var user_lat,user_lng;
            var map;
            function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            center: {lat:17, lng: 80},
                            zoom: 5
                            });
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat:17,lng:80},
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            }); 
    </script>
```

This is for testing purpose. I have to use this concept in another code. kindly help this.

This may be found as duplicate. There are many other posts which report same error, but none of the answers solved my problem.

Map is loading without any problem. initMap() function is executed. But the marker part is not coming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you have `async` and `defer` attributes, execution of the api library is deferred. When `marker` is being defined, the browser still haven't load the library, so `google.maps.Marker` is not defined.

Move the code where marker is defined inside `initMap()` function and it should work.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVD0ngfhOFs5rnww7UFyz9rN6UznOIZ1U&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
  var user_lat,user_lng;
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat:17, lng: 80},
      zoom: 5
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:17,lng:80},
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    }); 
  }
</script>
```

```js
var user_lat, user_lng;
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 17,
      lng: 80
    },
    zoom: 5
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 17,
      lng: 80
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You load your script with `async` flag. It means that a browser will not wait until this script will finish loading.

At the time of executing your `new google.maps.Map(`, it is still not loaded, and execution fails. Remove `async defer` flags from your `script` tag and make it load synchronously.

If you want the script to be loaded asynchronously, you need to use `callback` function.